# google cloud hard disk deleted. all data lost

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

My google cloud VM hard disk got full. So I tried to increase its size. I have done this before. This time things went differently. I increased the size. But the VM was not picking up the new size. So I stopped VM. Next thing I know, my VM got deleted and recreated, my hard disk returned to previous size with all data lost. It had my database with over 2 months of changes.

I admit I was careless not to backup. But currently my concern is, is there a way to retrieve the data. On Google Cloud, it shows $400 for Gold Plan which includes Tech Support. If I can be certain that they will be able to recover the data, I will am willing to pay. Does anyone know if I pay $400, the google support team will be able to recover the data?

If there are other ways to recover data, kindly let me know.

UPDATE:

Few people have shown interest in investigating this.
This most likely happened because by default "Auto-delete boot disk" option is selected which I was not aware of. But even then, I would expect auto-delete to happen when I delete the VM, not when I simply stopped it.

I am attaching screenshot of all activities that happened after I resized the boot partition. [image]

As you can see, I resized the disk at 2:00AM.
After receiving resize successful message, I stopped the VM.
Suddenly at 2:01, VM got deleted. 
At this point I had not checked notifications, I simply thought, it stopped. Then I started VM hoping to see new resized disk.
Instead of starting my VM, new VM was created with new disk and all previous data was lost.

I tried stopping and starting VM again. But the result was still the same.

UPDATE:
Adding activities before the incident.

[image]

Comment: While not helpful in this instance, you can never trust any single instance of your data. Providers have failures. Users do too, You need to have a backup/restore strategy that allows recovering from this. It won't be the last time. PS. Google won't care. Even for $400.

Comment: Agreed. Lesson learnt the hard way. Fortunately, I had created a snapshot couple weeks ago.

Comment: Given the chance, any provider will screw you over at the worst time. Google is an odd case. They're way to big to Vanish in the Night, but they're so big that they really just don't care unless you're sending them truckloads of money every month.

Comment: As a Googler who is trying to help, I can tell you that Google cares very much about all of its customers.

Comment: It would be helpful if you pasted (1) the stackdriver log of operations (2) the instance page for this instance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to recover deleted PDs.

You have no snapshots either?

Comment: I thought so too. I have snapshot from couple weeks back. But the data is critical. So I was hoping to regain all. Now I am in the process of the recreating all the lost data. What I don't understand, why GCP deleted my VM and hard disk when I stopped VM. I have restarted VM's before. This never happened

Comment: Can you try to repro your experience with a sacrificial VM and disk? If you are able to document a repro that includes stopping but not deleting a VM that is then deleted, then there's a problem that needs to be addressed. The default behavior is to auto-delete boot disks. Boot disks are often used as *the* disk on a VM but the better practice is to put (particularly) data on additional disks. The CLI and console don't default to auto-deleting additional disks. To prove the system behaves as expected, I created 4 VMs (console+gcloud, not|delete) and no disk was deleted by stopping VMs

Comment: "The default behavior is to auto-delete boot disks." I think this is what happened with me. Does this happen on VM termination/reset or also on stop and start. I had simply stopped the VM, not reset.

Comment: I have attached screenshot of the activities that occurred in my case.

Comment: The operations show instances being deleted. What were the commands that you ran that resulted in these consequences?

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, I resized my boot disk. then I stopped the VM expecting that restarting VM would result in picking up new disk size. Everything else happened automatically

Comment: The screenshot shows the resulting operations but it does not show what you did. I created an instance, resized the PD, resized the boot partition, stopped and restarted the instance without problem. Your operations show a "Delete VM" operation. This happened one of 2 ways: either there's a problem (which we're not able to repro) in which resizing then stopping a VM also deletes the disk; or some other process or user deleted the VM and the auto-delete of the boot disk was triggered.

Comment: The screenshot shows everything I did. 2:00 AM. <user> resized disk. 2:00AM <user> stopped VM postgres-server-group-kds. Resize disk and stop VM. There is nothing before this screenshot which is related to above actions. If you are interested, I would be happy to send all previous activities as well. FYI previous actives are from older days.  I am the only admin of this project. So there is no question of some other user causing this. Not sure about any other process. It is totally a mystery

Comment: I'm going to file a bug. I believe you. However, Engineering is going to ask for a repro and we're unable to do this. This presents a challenge in proving your experience and in proving that others may be affected by this.

Comment: Hi Daz, Added Screenshot of previous few days as well. Sure, if the engineering team needs anything from me, I will be more than happy to co-operate.

Comment: I've filed a bug and will report back when there's an update from Engineering.

Comment: The only explanation that we are able to provide aligns with @dany-l suggestion that a MIG was used to create these resources. With MIGs, stopping an instance has the effect of making the instance appear unhealthy to the controller, at which point it is deleted and recreated. This reflects the behavior you observed. Your resource naming `postgres-server-hkds` additionally supports this explanation too. I appreciate that you are confident this was not your case but we're unable to find another explanation.

Comment: For the MIG behavior, the documentation is unclear and we will revise it. See: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances#stateless

Comment: Hi DazWilkin, I feel so stupid. It did belong to a managed instance group.  The last time I checked, I looked at the wrong place. I checked it again and found it. Now it is coming back to me. The reason I forgot was because group was made 7-8 months ago and then later I realized I dont need a group for this instance. But, I did not remove it from group thinking that may be in the future I will use. Really apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. You wasted no-one's time. It's an easy thing to forget. We will make the documentation more clear because this difference needs to be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

The disk may have been marked for [auto-delete](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#updateautodelete).

However, this disk [shouldn't have been deleted](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stopping-or-deleting-an-instance#state_of_resources_for_stopped_instances) when the instance was stopped even if it was marked for auto-delete.

You can also only recover a [persistent disk from a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/restore-and-delete-snapshots).

Answer (score 0):

In a managed instance group, when you stop an instance, health check fails and the MIG deletes and recreates an instance if autoscaler is on. The process is discussed [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances#monitoring_groups). I hope that sheds some light if that is your use case.

Comment: Hi dany. This should not apply to my case because this instance does not belong to any instance group. It is a single VM with my database setup.

Comment: Look at the GCE VM instance logs in Stackdriver logging instead of the operation logs. There you will see an entry for ComputeInstance.delete entry. That log entry will show you the user who caused the deletion. Can you check which user deleted the instance?

Comment: I agree with @PatrickW that operation logs would be useful. Also, the name of your instance, with the prefix suggesting a "group" and characteristic suffix "-<random 4 characters>" suggest it was created by a MIG. Could you double check on your instances page if it is not in use by a group?

Comment: Hi dany and Grzenio, I feel so stupid right now. It did belong to a managed instance group. The last time I checked, I looked at the wrong place.. I checked it again and found it. Sorry guys for wasting your time.